# Inf , Sup functions

Tags: calculus

Suppose $X$, $Y$ sets and $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb R$.
How can I compute:

1. $\sup_xf(x, y)$
2. $\inf_yf(x, y)$

for any function from the type mentioned above? In case 1. this should be a function of $y$ right, and vice versa for case 2.? My ultimate goal is to prove the theorem:

$\quad sup_x\space inf_y \space f(x, y) ≤ inf_y \space sup_x \space f(x, y)$

Comment: What's stopping you? assuming the required sets are bounded above and below respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $y$ in $Y$ and define $f_{y}(x)\equiv f(x,y)$ as a function from $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $A\subset X$. Then, 
$$
\sup_{x\in A}f(x,y)\equiv\sup_{x\in A}f_{y}(x)\equiv\sup\left\{ f_{y}(A)\right\} .
$$
In other words, the above is the least upper bound of the image of $A$ under $f_{y}$, which is defined to be
$$
f_{y}(A)\equiv\left\{ f_{y}(x)\colon x\in A\right\} .
$$
In particular, if $f_{y}(A)$ is bounded above, since the real numbers satisfy [*the least upper bound property*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) (a.k.a. *Dedekind completeness*), there exists some real number $r$ such that
$$
r=\sup \left\{ f_{y}(A) \right\}.
$$
The number $r$ is your answer. Moreover, you are guaranteed the existence of a nondecreasing sequence in $f_y(A)$ converging to $r$. In terms of the original domain, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $f(x_n,y)\nearrow r$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

$\inf$ is defined similarly, and shares similar properties.